# What is the point of _=None in method python method signature?

Tags: python

What is the purpose of `_=None` in a method signature?

Example:

```
def method(_=None): 
    pass
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python might answer this partly or fully

Comment: Just note that ``_`` is a valid variable name. How it's used is more about convention most programmers will understand the code better.

Answer (score 4):

`_` is a conventional name for an unused placeholder variable in Python (and shell, and some other languages).

---

When not in the context of a class (that is, when defining a *function* rather than a *method*), this would define a function with a single optional (keyword) argument (defaulting to `None`), with a name indicating that that argument is deliberately unused (and exempting it from warnings about unused variables in some static-checking tools).

When defining a *method* where the first and only argument accepted is defined in this way, this becomes effectively a poor man's static method. That is to say, it's indicating that `self` is unused and optional, and allowing the method to be called independently of whether any object instance is associated (that is, whether a `self` is actually available at runtime).

Note that this is **not** common idiom, and using the [`@staticmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) is going to make much more sense to readers of your code.